# Saving output label values to csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python, and maybe this is a very basic question but I'm not getting a solution of this issue. I'm working on a classification problem, there are 40 classes I've trained the model and tested over test data. I'm getting labels of around 4000+, 1 label across each image in a test data. I want to save all these 4000+ labels in a CSV file. I've written a code the problem is when I run the code only the last label is saving into the CSV file, how can I save all the labels in a single column of a CSV file.

```
import csv
Labels=[]

model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():

    for data in test_loader:
        output=model(data)
        Labels.append(output.argmax().item())
        print(output.argmax().item())

        
x = output.argmax().item()
reader = [[x]]

with open('Submission.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)              
    thewriter.writerows(reader)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

model.eval()

with open('Submission.csv', 'a+', newline='') as f:  # 'a+' means append to a file
 thewriter = csv.writer(f)
 
 with torch.no_grad():
   for data in test_loader:
     output=model(data)
     label = output.argmax().item()  # this your label
     print(label)
     thewriter.writerow([label])
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan It is working, the only thing is, it is writing twice. Like there are around 4000 labels so there should be around 4000 rows in a column of a csv file but there are around 8000 rows in the column. the same labels are repeating after 4000.

Comment: I think you are running the code twice. Because it adds your labels to the same file. Please delete the first "Submission.csv" file and then run it only once.

Comment: Each time when you run it, it adds labels to the same "Submission.csv" file.